# Using Jquery to Convert XML to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have data in XML format and want to use Jquery to print it out to HTML, but somehow the result doesn't show up.  What am I missing here?  Please help [Live Code](http://jsfiddle.net/R37mC/450/)

JS

```
var xml='<Pages>
<Page Name="test">
    <controls>      
        <test>this is a test.</test>
    </controls>
</Page>    
<Page Name = "User">
    <controls>
       <name>Sunil</name>
    </controls>
</page>
</Pages>';


    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ); 
$($xml).each(function(){
var found = $('this').find("Page[Name]>controls>name").text();
    $('#main').append(found);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Javascript doesn't support implicit multi-line strings. You have to do one of the following:

```
var test = "String" +
           "String2

var test2 = "String \
            String2"
```

(2) There is an error in your XML. The last `</page>` should be `</Page>`

(3) JQuery is very smart, you could do what you want in a simpler manner:

```
$(xml).find("Page[Name]>controls>name").each(function(index, el) {
    $('#main').append($(el).text());
});
```

Updated Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/R37mC/452/